# How to fix indentation of items below header 3 in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, indentation

In org mode, when I do a header 1 or 2, the bullets beneath it snaps to align under the header.

But bullets do not indent under for header 3. How do I edit this?

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this using plain Org mode plus `org-indent-mode` and with fixed pitch fonts. It seems like your are using a fixed pitch font in the headings and a variable pitch font in the contents? Also what are you using to format the bullets? `org-modern`? `org-superstar-mode`? It likely matters too. Is the indentation only wrong for items or for regular text too?

Comment: ill look into these items and update my question shortly.

Comment: @orgtre this is helpful. I changed the normal text to a monospace font and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Other than changing the text to a monospace font, a solution which allows one to retain a variable-width font in both the heading and the entry text is given [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/76133/33424). However, a problem (see link) when using wide unicode bullets still remains, so a more general solution would be great.